# Product of Tiled Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have some matrix $A$, and that $B$ is given by:

$B = AA$

Matrix $C$ is composed by tiling $A$ 3 times in a diagonal fashion, with other entries being zeros:

$C = \left( \begin{matrix}A&0&0\\0&A&0\\0&0&A\end{matrix} \right)$

Matrix $D$ is formed similarly from $B$:

$D = \left( \begin{matrix}B&0&0\\0&B&0\\0&0&B\end{matrix} \right)$

Is it possible to show, then, that:

$D = CC$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Consider what happens when you form $CC$ by matrix multiplication.  When you multiply the first row of $C$ by each of the first three columns of $C$ you get the first row of $AA$ followed by zeros.  When you multiply the first row of $C$ by any of the last six rows of $C$ you get zero.  Keep going like this.  You can write out a formal proof by chasing the indices, keeping track of which entries are known to be zero to reduce the range of the summations.